# What's the difference between let and set?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I don't know much of the theory behind Vim. It looks as if we `set` some variables, and `let` other variables. What's the difference, and when is one required over the other?

Also, the solarized vim colorscheme says to `let g:blabla...` what is the significance of `g:` in this instance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990219/vim-whats-the-difference-between-let-and-set

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`let` assigns a value to a variable, and `set` assigns a value to one of Vim's internal options.

For example, you would use

```
:let mystring='Hello!'
```

to declare a new variable, but you would use

```
:set tabstop=4
```

or

```
:set expandtab
```

to set one of Vim's options.

See also: `:help let`, `:help set`.

`g:` simply signifies a global variable. There are several of these "variable namespaces"—from `:help internal-variables`:

```
        (nothing) In a function: local to a function; otherwise: global
|buffer-variable|    b:   Local to the current buffer.
|window-variable|    w:   Local to the current window.
|tabpage-variable|   t:   Local to the current tab page.
|global-variable|    g:   Global.
|local-variable|     l:   Local to a function.
|script-variable|    s:   Local to a |:source|'ed Vim script.
|function-argument|  a:   Function argument (only inside a function).
|vim-variable|       v:   Global, predefined by Vim.
```

Comment: Do note that you can set vim's internal options using `let` by doing `let &{option name}=value`

Answer (score 14):

`:set` is used for internal options and handles the types of the option. It allows things like inversion of boolean options (e.g. `:set invpaste`) adding and removing settings from a list (e.g. `:set dictionary-=/tmp/myfile`).

`:let`, on the other hand, allows access to a plethora of changeable things in vim, including regular variables, options, registers, etc. and the value being set is the result of evaluating an expression, instead of a simple value like with `:set`, which means `:let` gives you access to math, string manipulation, and functions.

For example, you can `:let &dictionary=/tmp/myfile` to set the option `'dictionary'` to `/tmp/myfile` (thus modifying the same option shown above in the `:set` example)

You can set a global variable with `:let g:myvar=42`. The prefix you asked about provides scope. [Doorknob's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2077/227) covers the scoping very well.

You can `:let @a="Some text"` to change the contents of register a to contain `Some text`, which you could later paste with `"ap` for example.

You can `:let $PATH = $PATH . ":/home/me/bin"` to append your own bin directory to the `PATH` environment variable, which is passed to any external commands executed by Vim (this works for any environment variable).

Although `let` has some pretty powerful abilities (like `:let $MYFILE = @%` to set an environment variable to the filename of the current buffer), it doesn't know that a setting is a boolean, so it doesn't offer nice accesses or error checking like `:set` does.

In the end, it's about using the best tool for the job. If you want to simply modify an option, `:set` is your tool. If you want to move information around between registers, options, variables, or base your value on the result of an expression, then `:let` is your tool.

Although you explicitly asked about Vim, another thing to note is that `:set` is more common in the vi/Vim families, where `:let` is less common (for example, nvi doesn't have a `let` command, and viemu doesn't provide access to registers via `let`).